# mystirious Delete Statement Generated by Hibernate while selecting data

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I have an Oracle DB view combined from 2 identical tables using union all keyword,

I created a tree of classes on it using hibernate's 'table per class heirarchy' mapping as follows:

```
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
<class name="com.ntg.shefaa.model.impl.Medical"
    discriminator-value="0" table="MEDICAL_INFORMATIONS" lazy="true">

    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="id" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>

    <discriminator column="TYPE" type="integer" not-null="false" />
<!-- and the rest of the attributes go here .... -->
<subclass name="com.ntg.shefaa.model.impl.Hospital"
        discriminator-value="1">
</subclass>
<!-- and the rest of the subclasses go here .... -->
```

My Entities POJOs are:

```
public class Medical {
private Integer id;
//the rest of the common attributes go here ...
}
public class Hospital extends Medical {
  private int type = 1;
  // the rest of the specific attributes go here
}
```

the problem is when I try to select select data using hibernate criteria APIs, Hibernate generates an "DELETE" statement after the select statement:

```
Hibernate: select * from ( 
     select this_.id as id1_2_0_, this_.FACILITY_NAME as FACILITY3_2_0_, this_.FAMOUS_NAME as FAMOUS4_2_0_, this_.GOE_ID as GOE5_2_0_, this_.GOVERNORATE_NAME as GOVERNOR6_2_0_, this_.ADDRESS as ADDRESS7_2_0_, this_.PHONE1 as PHONE8_2_0_, this_.PHONE2 as PHONE9_2_0_, this_.PHONE3 as PHONE10_2_0_, this_.LONGITUDE as LONGITU11_2_0_, this_.LATITUDE as LATITUD12_2_0_, this_.DEGREE as DEGREE13_2_0_, this_.GENDER as GENDER14_2_0_, this_.SPECIALIZATION as SPECIAL15_2_0_, this_.QUALIFICATION as QUALIFI16_2_0_, this_.TYPE as TYPE2_2_0_, clinics2_.ID as ID1_2_2_, clinics2_.FACILITY_NAME as FACILITY3_2_2_, clinics2_.FAMOUS_NAME as FAMOUS4_2_2_, clinics2_.GOE_ID as GOE5_2_2_, clinics2_.GOVERNORATE_NAME as GOVERNOR6_2_2_, clinics2_.ADDRESS as ADDRESS7_2_2_, clinics2_.PHONE1 as PHONE8_2_2_, clinics2_.PHONE2 as PHONE9_2_2_, clinics2_.PHONE3 as PHONE10_2_2_, clinics2_.LONGITUDE as LONGITU11_2_2_, clinics2_.LATITUDE as LATITUD12_2_2_ 
     from MEDICAL_INFORMATIONS this_ 
     left outer join MEDICAL_INFORMATIONS clinics2_ 
     on this_.id=clinics2_.ID and ( clinics2_.type=2) 
) where rownum <= ?

Hibernate: delete from MEDICAL_INFORMATIONS where ID=? and FACILITY_NAME=? and FAMOUS_NAME=? and GOE_ID=? and GOVERNORATE_NAME=? and ADDRESS=? and PHONE1=? and PHONE2=? and PHONE3=? and LONGITUDE=? and LATITUDE=?
```

sometimes I get a hibernate exception that It can't delete from the DB view and sometimes not, However I wonder why hibernate generated the delete statement and what entity it is trying to delete???

the code I use to select the data looks like this //per each call :

```
Session currentSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
currentSession.beginTransaction();
Criteria criteria = currentSession.createCriteria(type);
Object output = criteria.list();
session.getTransaction().commit();
session.flush();
session.close();
```

my hibernate config file is:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">CREATE</property> -->
    <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode">NONE</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="format_sql">false</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.3.63:1521/testdb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">tl</property>
    <property name="connection.password">hggi</property>
    <mapping resource="config/Medical.hbm.xml" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HELP!

thanks in advance;

Comment: this is scary, man!

Comment: Why are you opening a transaction (and commiting it) to execute just a select statement?

Comment: @Jorge Campos : I just made this for all types of statements (select - create - update - delete), anyway: what do you recommend in case of select statement?

Comment: At least for select statements you don't need a transaction it is an overkill. You just open a session execute it and close. As per the misterious delete statement I wouldn't know.

Comment: @Jorge Campos , although All the examples/tutorials about hibernate I've seen open a transaction and close it for select statements : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm >>> I followed Your advise and suddenly! the misterious delete statement vanished!!! thank you very much Sir

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3098644/whats-the-point-to-enclose-select-statements-in-a-transaction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976686/is-there-a-difference-between-a-select-statement-inside-a-transaction-and-one-th http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818465/sql-server-transaction-and-select-statement These tutorial sites tends to not explain it very good. The only thing that will justify a select inside a transaction is if in the SAME transaction you execute a insert, update, delete statement so that select will get the affected results.